# How do I connect multiple Mac computers through a wireless router?

Tags: macos, wireless-networking, networking

I'm not sure if this is very easy and I'm stupid for having trouble with it, or if it's very hard and am stupid for thinking it should be easier...

I've got two Mac computers, one running OS 10.4, one running OS 10.5.  Both are connected to the same wireless router using DHCP.  (It's a 2WIRE, if it matters.)  I'd like to be able to transfer files between the two computers using this connection, rather than using the *slow* bluetooth that we're using at present.

What do I need to do to accomplish this?  Will I need to do any special router configuration, or just configure the computers properly?  Is there anything special I should know before I take this on?  Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have the same configuration and sharing works just fine.

Have you tried to ping the other computer?

Have you checked whether sharing is activated on the remote computer?

Have you tried Go>>Connect to Server, and browse for available servers?

Comment: Yeah, this should be pretty simple. Check **File Sharing** in System Preferences >> Sharing. Then you should be able to see the Public folder from other Macs on your network.